# How to run Spring Boot app in debug mode via Maven command?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I am trying to to run my Spring Boot app via command line by passing environment variables. But in each case (I have tried many combinations), my app reads these values from application.yml file instead of command. And gives the following error:

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "${DB_USERNAME}"

On the other hand, when I run my app using IntelliJ IDEA by passing the following environment variables on Run configuration, it works without any problem.

***IntelliJ IDEA Run Configuration > Environment variables:***

```
DB_NAME=demo;DB_USERNAME=postgres;DB_PASSWORD=pass;JWT_SECRET=secretKey
```

Similarly, when I run the same command on project root via `mvnw` it works.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug" 
-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--DB_NAME=demo 
--DB_USERNAME=postgres --DB_PASSWORD=pass --JWT_SECRET=secretKey"
```

But I want to run IntelliJ IDEA on debug mode using command and passing these parameters (environment variables). So, how can I do this? And why the same command is not working when I try with "Run anything" window on IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: coma between params

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments

Comment: @ShakirovRamil I tried with comma as `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug" -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--DB_NAME=demo,--DB_USERNAME=postgres,--DB_PASSWORD=pass,--JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey"`, but does not make any sense. Any idea?

Comment: And this also gives the same FATAL error: `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--DB_NAME=demo,--DB_USERNAME=postgres,--DB_PASSWORD=pass,--JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey`

Comment: What will I do with program argument on IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same configuration and run the application in debug mode with the right next button of the Run Button in IntelliJ.

Comment: I don't want to use button.